# Statistical differences between longitudinal and cross-sectional data

Tags: time-series, panel-data, inference, cross-section

I would like to start a follow-up discussion to an existing question on cross-validated:  [Difference between longitudinal design and time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7110/difference-between-longitudinal-design-and-time-series).

Most of the answers there tend to make distinctions between the data sets themselves and not between the analysis or modeling done with the data. **Are there distinctions between the treatment of the data, and not the data itself?**

For example, are there any differences in the inferential methods used on cross-sectional and longitudinal data, or is the only difference between the two the interpretation of the results and the verbiage you use to describe the study?

Answer (score 1):

The *names* are applied largely based on the structural characteristics of the dataset.  To quote from @JeromyAnglim's [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7123/7290) there:

> If we think of designs made up of $n$ cases measured on $k$ occasions, then the following loose definition seems to me to be descriptive of the distinction:
>
> - longitudinal designs: high $n$, low $k$
> - time series: low $n$, high $k$

To those two possibilities, we can add *cross-sectional* datasets.  They have only one measurement occasion per case (i.e., $k=1$, but $N>1$ and hopefully reasonably large).

---

However, we certainly need to take those features into account when analyzing the data, no matter what we call it.  The key aspect from a statistical perspective is that longitudinal / time-series data are not independent, whereas cross-sectional data may be.  If existing non-independence isn't taken into account, any inferences will be invalid (e.g., confidence intervals may be too narrow).

- If you have cross-sectional data, standard, statistics-101-level analyses (e.g., a $t$-test), can be applied.
- If you have time-series data ($n=1$, large $k$), analysts will often use [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) methods to identify auto-regressive, integrative, and moving average terms.
- With longitudinal data ($k>1$ , but small), there usually isn't enough information to estimate ARIMA terms.  Instead, people will typically use [mixed effects models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model).