# Predicting distribution as target

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, dependent-variable

Are there any ways to predict distributions as target?
For example we have user's profile and data from social network. And his followers age distribution:

```
0.3 < 18 y.o.
18 y.o. < 0.5 < 45 y.o.
0.2 > 45 y.o.
```

How can we predict such distribution for new users?
It's possible to predict as probabilities of each class and then do a softmax, but there definitely should be some modern and more complex approaches to such task.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is [functional-data-analysis](/questions/tagged/functional-data-analysis):

> Functional Data Analysis defines a framework where the fundamental units of analysis are functions.

Your functions are densities.

This thread should be useful: [Why is Functional Data Analysis (FDA) not as popular?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/564537/1352)

Comment: I disagree. Maybe FA can be used for something like that, but primarily it's a different problem